# Warning "No map received" occurs, when trying to visualize map in rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am trying to visualize a map in rviz using slam_gmapping on my youbot. When adding the display Map to rviz and choosing map as topic the warning "No map received" occurs. I can visualize the sensor data in rviz by adding the display laser scan but it does not create a map.
I searched for this error in ros answers but could not find an answer fixing my problem.

The ROS_MASTER_URI is set to my youbot: ROS_MASTER_URI=http: //Jakobs-youBot:11311/

My tf tree is map -> odom -> base_footprint -> scan.

My laser scan topic is scan.

I am starting slam_gmapping with

```
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
```

and do not get any output after starting it. Is this supposed to be like that?

I am using a youbot with ubuntu 12.04 and ROS hydro. My the laser i am using is a hokuyo laser.

I really do not have any idea what i am doing wrong. If anyone can help me, i would really appreciate it. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179245/warning-%22no-map-received%22-occurs,-when-trying-to-visualize-map-in-rviz/) by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your laser topic is scan you should not add the remapping `scan:=base_scan`. This would tell gmapping that the laser topic is base_scan.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-07-05**:
when using the remapping i do not get any warnings in my terminal. When not adding it i get the warning: Failed to compute laser pose, aborting initialization ("base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist. )

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-05**:
Good! This mean that it received a scan now. Your TF setup seems to be missing something. You need to check if the mentioned frames exist or give the correct ones as parameters to gmapping.

**Comment by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) on 2014-08-05**:
Yes, that helped a lot. Tanks. I wrote a launch file, that uses my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My gmapping.launch file that solved the problem:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <rosparam>
      odom_frame: odom
      map_update_interval: 0.5
      maxUrange: 30.0
      maxRange: 60.0
      sigma: 0.05
      kernelSize: 1
      lstep: 0.05
      astep: 0.05
      iterations: 5
      lsigma: 0.075
      ogain: 3.0
      lskip: 0
      linearUpdate: 0.5
      angularUpdate: 0.436
      temporalUpdate: -1.0
      resampleThreshold: 0.5
      particles: 80
      xmin: -1.0
      ymin: -1.0
      xmax: 1.0
      ymax: 1.0
      delta: 0.025
      llsamplerange: 0.01
      llsamplestep: 0.01
      lasamplerange: 0.005
      lasamplestep: 0.005
      base_frame: base_footprint
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [m.hoev](https://answers.ros.org/users/16886/m.hoev/) with karma: 68 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2